# How many and which partitions should I create for a linux server?

Tags: linux, unix, partition

Partitions are very important on Linux server because it give you a lot of flexibility, for example when upgrading to a bigger hard drive.

But, how many partitions should I create when building a Linux box ?
Which size should I set for each partition ?

At last but not least, which partitions should I have on a separate disk (I'm thinking about /home, /var on perhaps a quicker drive, etc) and which partitions may I share on same drive ?

Comment: How many drives do you have? do you anticipate that number changing over time? Is this a single-purpose box or a general purpose one?  Single user or multi?  All these things matter.

Comment: The question is more on a general purpose but still for servers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Planning a good partitioning structure is heavily dependent on actually knowing how you are going to use the 'server'.  Any random advice that doesn't take the actual services that will be provided isn't going to be particularly useful.

For example if it is a debian-based box that will be used for mysql you might want a seperate partitions for /,/var, and /var/lib/mysql.

Is it going to be a file server with lots of shared storage?  You might want a /, /home, and /srv partitions.

For a box running only squid, you might want on partition for /, and one partition on a fast disk for the squid spool.

As you are planning your partitions it is very helpful to have a good understanding of the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) and if/how your chose distro deviates from the standard.

Using [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) can make it much easier to change your mind in the future and adjust your partitions without having to reboot., and its ability to create snapshots can be very easy to create good backups.

Comment: The best answer so far.

Comment: Great answer .. both the recommendation that the structure is dependent on intended use and that LVM is a good way to go.

Comment: See more information about the value of partitioning over here.
http://serverfault.com/questions/61284/sell-partitioning-to-me

Comment: I wasn't even aware that there _was_ a Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 8):

I always create these partitions, and as of the last year, always on LVM:

```
/       - a few Gig
/usr    - 24 Gig and mostly empty
/var    - 4 Gig works for me, YMMV
/home   - depends on how many users you will have
```

One of the most important is `/var` -- if this is a separate partition, then when it fills up, you will not crash your root partition.  Although I have never done this, some make a separate `/usr` so that they can mount it read-only.

and I sometimes create these partitions:

```
/boot   - even 1 Gig is way more than enough
```

The reasoning is that it's not always possible to boot from a RAID or LVM partition.  Thus, `/boot` can be a simple ext3 partition, allowing `/` to be more advanced.

If I will have a large number of large files, I will sometimes create a specific partition for these large files so the filesystem can be tweaked to be efficient at storing large files.  Some people, if they will be serving NFS from a server, will create a separate partition for their NFS shares or even a separate partition for each NFS share. This depends on your needs.

Why LVM?  As I've mentioned in answers elsewhere but forgot to mention here, it makes it a LOT easier to change your mind later and expand a partition.  This has saved my butt already.

These are general guidelines.  Of course, I expect that if your server has special needs, you'll take that into account and make partition reflecting these needs.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you're building a machine that's going to last a while,
would be inconvenient to rebuild, and needs to be pretty flexible, you
might like a scheme similar to the following:

1. Install a minimum of two physical drives, the same size; for the
   purposes of this example, I'm going to assume 500GB SATA drives, but the
   principles work just fine with other sizes of drive.
2. Partition each drive as follows:

   ```
   /dev/sda1   500MB
   /dev/sda2   100GB
   /dev/sda3   the rest
   ```

   The goal is to have a dinky 500MB partition up front, a sizeable
   partition in the middle for the OS and applications, and the bulk of
   the drive at the back for additional data.
3. Build a SW RAID 1 set, `/dev/md0`, from `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`;
   build additional SW RAID 1 sets `/dev/md1` and `/dev/md2` from the
   corresponding paritions.
4. Format `/dev/md0` as ext3; this will be `/boot`.
5. Format `/dev/md1` and `/dev/md2` as LVM physical volumes.
6. Create a LVM volume group, `vg_system`, which contains `/dev/md1`.
7. Create appropriate LVM volumes inside `vg_system` for your various OS
   partitions; at the very least, you'll want `swap`, `/var` of a couple
   GB, and `/` of 10GB or so.
   **NOTE**: do not allocate all of `vg_system`!  When you later decide
   that you want to increase the size of `\var`, or you want to add an
   `/opt` or whatnot, then you'll want that additional space.
8. Create a LVM volume group, `vg_data`, which contains `/dev/md2`.
9. Create LVM volumes inside `vg_data` as desired; at the very least
   you'll want a sizeable `/home`, and you may want additional volumes
   for, say, mail spools, or databases, or web roots, or any other data
   that isn't part of the OS.
   Again, don't allocate all of `vg_data`, for reasons similar to the
   ones listed above.

The advantages of this strategy include the following:

- It's tolerant of hardware failures; either drive can fail without
  causing a system failure, and if you invest in a hot-swap controller,
  you can recover without downtime.
- It's future-proof and expandable; when you buy 2TB drives a few years
  down the road, you can slap them into the machine, make them into
  another SW RAID set, format it as an LVM physical volume, add it to
  whichever volume group needs more space (probably `lv_data`), then use
  `pvmove` to migrate your data off the old drives and onto the new.
  In addition, major OS updates can be rendered significantly less
  painful; if you need to reinstall the OS for a major upgrade (ahem
  Red Hat :( ), you can do so while preserving home directories (and
  mail spools and whatever all else you put in `vg_data`).

The disadvantages of this strategy are few; I suppose it's a bit
complex, and you do take a performance hit on writes because of the RAID
1.  However, I've been building workstations and standalone servers
according to these principles for some years now, and in my experience
every time I don't build a machine along these lines, before long I wish
I had.

-steve

P.S. I should add that if you have the infrastructure in place to
quickly and painlessly provision a new machine, then a system like this
is overkill; rather than tinkering with RAID sets and LVM, just rebuild
the machine if you need something changed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the partitions mentioned by Eddie, I typically create two more separate partitions

/tmp  - for the same reasons you created a separate /var partition (I've had the temp space all fill up before).   I typically go with 1-2 GB

/usr/local - This allows you to upgrade and clean /usr as needed without blowing away all your separately installed software.  The size here depends on how much external software you install.  I typically go with about 10 GB but am finding that to be a bit small these days.

I always make /home last and fill up the rest of the disk with it.

On the /boot partition, I've never made it bigger than 100 Mb and never run into space problems (I clean out old kernels eventually).  It really can be very small.

Also don't forget a swap partition as well.

Answer (score 2):

For years every computer I've used has been a dual boot system, and on the Linux side I pretty much stuck with this schema (I'm talking personal workstations here, no server stuff, so your mileage might vary)

```
/     - main thing
/boot - not that relevant, since cylinder being < 1024 and 
        exotic filesystems are no longer an issue
/home - handy if you upgrade your laptop with each new distro :-)
```

For my last upgrade I did an install from scratch, wiping out my `/` partition. That made me think a separate `/opt` or `/usr/local` partition would have been nice, sparing me the hassle of reinstalling all the stuff I put in there (java, eclipse... I usually don't care for the distro packaged ones).

Answer (score 1):

For most machines, I do

```
100MB /boot
1GB * NUMBER_OF_USERS /home
10GB /var/log
10GB /var
REST /
```

In some cases, this will need to be switched, but I'm pretty adamant about users not getting more than 1GB of space on a server.  If they need more, they can use /tmp, with the understanding that it will be deleted via cron nightly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't use a hardware RAID there - under Linux I would always use LVM on top of RAID. Even for a single disk configuration. Reason being that you have the option to add more storage space (by extending the LVM group) or change the redundancy options (say turning a "weird" single disk raid1 config into a mirrored one or even RAID10 with some heavy lifting).

To answer your question I usually have something similar to this for a generic server. Starting with 2 disks (say a 1RU Dell), both partitioned as:

- ~100MB RAID1 for /boot
- LVM on top of RAID1 for the rest of the disk

Then we create all the volume as LVM volumes:
 * /
 * /var
 * /tmp
 * /home
 * /opt

I would avoid creating too much filesystems as it's a pain to manage. If you are running low on disk you will end up having free space across many filesystem but not enough to do work on.

/home and /tmp on a separate filesystem is always a good idea; generally I don't separate /opt unless I'm planning to put a lot of stuff in it. (NFS might be a better option for /opt if you have lots of servers that requires the same software stack)

In short, use LVM for everything unless you have a reason not to - that way you have the option to change.

Also, use a log server so logs won't fill up your /var!

Answer (score 0):

- /boot - 128MB

Volume Group - rootvg

- /var - 5GB (depends if it's used as a mail server. You can also resize to catch core files)
- /tmp - 2GB
- /opt - 10GB (used for software that doesn't come with the distro)
- / - 6GB - minumum

Volume Group - datavg

- /home - the rest

You can make a separate /usr for your software but in my case the box gets reinstalled, so no need to get its own partition.