# Debian - What is the purpose of splitting root folder into separate partitions?

Tags: linux, debian, partition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sell partitioning to me](https://serverfault.com/questions/61284/sell-partitioning-to-me)

Actually, my whole / folder is into a single partition.

So what is the purpose of putting, for instance, the /var/log folder or the /home folder into an other partition on the same hard drive?

Are there any performance gains, or is this just for maintenance purposes?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thx for the advice Zoredache.

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/1145/how-many-and-which-partitions-should-i-create-for-a-linux-server/1431#1431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Center for Internet Security (CIS) [Debian Benchmark](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform) recommends placing the following directories
on their own partitions:

- /home
- /tmp
- /var
- /opt

And optionally

- /var/tmp
- /var/log
- /var/spool/mail
- /var/cache/apt/archives

From a security standpoint this can help prevent users from doing things such as filling up
partitions, depleting the inode pool, etc.  From a functional standpoint, it can help you grow partitions only where needed as you find a need for more space. It also gives you the flexibility of placing partitions on different devices, such as /home on a network volume, or /var on fast storage.

Answer (score 3):

A few reasons come to mind...

- Excessive log volume will only fill /var, allowing other processes to get the space they need in places like /tmp
- Better control of mount options. (ie: nosuid on /home filesystem )
- More flexibility for partitions and filesystems (ie: multiple Linux OSes, followed by a RAID1 /home )

I typically just do '/', '/var', and '/home'.  Personally, I'm very strict about /home in particular, so it's easy to differentiate my userdata from everything else.

Answer (score 1):

1. Keeping one full directory from impacting other parts of the system.  A separate /home means a user gone wild isn't going to impact /var, /usr, or other system directories.
2. Backups.  The fifth field in /etc/fstab can be used to choose whether the filesystem would be dumped by the `dump` command.  Separate partitions means you can choose individually which to back up.

Comment: /home and /tmp are probably most common since non-root users can write there by default.  /var or /var/log is common since logs can fill up the FS.  There's no hard, fast rule about it, so it's a good idea to think along the lines of "what's the risk and impact of /some/directory filling up?"